# Why i'm not geeting Table data in second column after adding first data from DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

2nd column(sub tables) not showing in main table.
if i remove data from sql database getting then it shows. whats the problem?  i try all possible solutions.

1st sub tables gets data from database 
2nd sub table not showing..
also tried with while loop

```html
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
            <th width="33%"> mt</th>
            <th width="33%"> send</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="5%"> No </th>
      <th width="14%"> col1 </th>
      <th width="8%"> col2 </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php $res = mysqli_query($link,"select * from type")or die (mysql_error());
 $srn=1;
 for($i=0;$fs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)or die (mysql_error());$i++){?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $srn; $srn++; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $fs["type"]; ?></td>
      <td><a href="editproduct.php?id=<?php echo $fs['type']; ?>">
        <button class="btn btn-warning"></button>
        </a> <a href="deleteproduct.php?id=<?php echo $fs['type']; ?>">
        <button class="btn btn-danger"></button>
        </a> </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td> 
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="5%"> no </th>
        <th width="14%"> col1 </th>
        <th width="8%"> col2 </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="record">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I dont understand. What is not showing and what is showing?

Comment: 2nd column data not showing @RiggsFolly

Comment: change your for loop to a while loop

Comment: also tried not working @RiggsFolly

Comment: Please update your question to reveal your updated code that supposedly follows  Riggs' advice.  And upgrade your `mysql_` functions to `mysqli_`  In your last subtable you have 3 th and 2 td.  Fetch_assoc doesn't need `or die`